# Global Spec and Vector Bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Can anybody explain why the vector bundle corresponding to a locally free sheaf F is global spec of sym of the **dual** of F and not just F?  How does a section get identified with a polynomial in the dual?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_algebra

Comment: I suggest you work it out when the base scheme is Spec of a field.

Comment: Linear functions on V are elements of V^*, so polynomial functions on V are elements of Sym(V^*).

Comment: Functoriality .

Comment: Or maybe when you say "corresponding to" you're thinking of a different correspondence from the rest of us. 

Comment: General strategy for these kinds of questions: pick a torus action.  Look at the corresponding torus action on whatever you're thinking about and check if the weights have changed sign.

Answer (score 2):

Let $L$ be a locally free ${\cal O}_X$-module of finite rank. Define $V=Spec(Sym(L^\vee))$. Then 
$$Mor_X(X, V)={\cal O}_X-Alg(Sym(L^\vee), {\cal O}_X)=Hom(L^\vee, {\cal O}_X)=L(X).$$
The universal mapping property of the (global) Spec is in EGA II.1.